# Pixel extraction using image masking?

Tags: image, numpy, opencv

I have two pictures.
[image]

[image]

I want to extract the pixels in the regions marked by their respective color. (The normal distribution of the pixels in yellow and red)

I know opencv supports bitwise operation, however, I've only seen it being done with black/white mask.

I thought about using np.where(), I am curious to see if there's a better solution?

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting please? The mean of the pixels masked in yellow? The number of pixels masked with red?

Comment: the number of pixels in the region masked with red/yellow

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of red/yellow pixels like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('abYaj.png')

# Make mask of red pixels - True where red, false elsewhere
redMask = (im[:, :, 0:3] == [0,0,255]).all(2)

# Count red pixels
redTotal = np.count_nonzero(redMask)            # redTotal=44158

# Make mask of yellow pixels
yellowMask = (im[:, :, 0:3] == [0,255,255]).all(2)

# Count yellow pixels
yellowTotal = np.count_nonzero(yellowMask)      # yellowTotal=356636
```

---

Alternatively, you could just use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal to count them and write no code at all:

```
magick identify -verbose abYag.png

Image:
  Filename: abYaj.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1024x1024+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  ...
  ...
  Colors: 3
  Histogram:
    647782: (0,0,0,0) #00000000 none
    44158: (255,0,0,255) #FF0000FF red             <--- HERE
    356636: (255,255,0,255) #FFFF00FF yellow       <--- HERE
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I should express my question more clearly. It seems like you're counting the number of yellow/red pixels in the "mask". I want to use those color to select the "region of interest" in the original image. As in, what pixels are contained within that region marked by the yellow / red blobs.

Comment: That's exactly what you answered in the comments when I asked you to clarify what you wanted! If you want to do something with the pixels in the original image, you can just AND them with the masks I worked out since my masks are Boolean True/False at each pixel location.

Comment: Can you explain how you can perform bitwise AND on a tuple (RGB) since that's what the original image is represented as? I know opencv provides the function, but I assume you would have to somehow map the tuples to an integer?

Comment: How could the original image be a tuple? You are using **OpenCV** which stores images as Numpy arrays and you refer to `np.where()` in your question. Please state clearly exactly what you want as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I am reading the image like this. img = cv2.imread(name, COLOR_BGR2RGB). Since each pixel has three channels, it makes sense that it is a tuple? Printing out img gives something like [[255,255,255],[255,255,255]....]. I want to know how can I perform a bitwise AND using the image and mask above. Thank you

Comment: That is not the correct way to read an image with `cv2.imread()`. Please click `edit` under your original question and add your code and clearly state what you are trying to do. Thank you.